# Why does return return undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
    function getLogin(){
        var login = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let res; // variable
        login.open('POST', 'assets/php/get_player.php', true);
        login.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        login.send();
        login.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (login.readyState == 4) {
                if(login.status == 200) {
                    res = login.responseText; //Here the variable changes
                }
            }
        }
        return res
    }

    startbtn.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (getLogin() == "true"){ // Here it gives undefined

            }else{
                alert("Вы не вошли в свой аккаунт!");
            }

        })
    });
```

The 'res' variable changes, but 'return' returns undefined
Here is a code that does not work
Here is a code that does not work

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Comment: Performing a request is asynchronous, but you are treating it as synchronous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are dealing with async actions, the response from the server will always be received after JavaScript is done executing the `getLogin` function. You should resolve the result and await for it (notice how the functions are now async)

```js
async function getLogin() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var login = new XMLHttpRequest();
    login.open("POST", "assets/php/get_player.php", true);
    login.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    login.send();
    login.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (login.readyState === 4) {
        if (login.status === 200) {
          resolve(login.responseText);
        } else {
          reject("Status is not ok");
        }
      }
    };
  });
}

startbtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    try {
      const loginResult = await getLogin();
      if (loginResult == "true") {
      } else {
        alert("Вы не вошли в свой аккаунт!");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error during login");
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
});
```

You can also use a sync request (though that's not recommended)

```js
function getLogin() {
  var login = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let res;
  login.open("POST", "assets/php/get_player.php", false); // false = not async
  login.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  login.send();
  if (login.readyState === 4) {
    if (login.status === 200) {
      res = login.responseText;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

startbtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (getLogin() === "true") {
    } else {
      alert("Вы не вошли в свой аккаунт!");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ```js
const startbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".start-game");

startbtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    const loginResult = await getLogin();
    if (loginResult == "true") {
    } else {
      alert("Вы не вошли в свой аккаунт!");
    }
  }); // Uncaught (in promise)
});
```

gives the following error